# Telegram bot send document

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created a bot to Telegram in python that allows you to send any file, but unfortunately allows me to send a maximum of 50 MB (I integrated the library telepot) I wanted to ask if you can take advantage of the limit which offers telegram, or 1.5 gb?

Answer (score 1):

The 50mb limit isnt from teapot, but the telegram bot api itself.

From the [Telegram Bot API Documentation:](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files)

> Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.

So no, you cannot upload files above 50mb.

Answer (score 1):

With [local Telegram Bot API server](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server) you are allowed to send files with a 2000Mb file size limit, raised from 50Mb default.